# VS2010 Add new data source wizard crash

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Recently I had a problem with VS2010. I could not add a new data source of type 'object' to my windows application project.
I select add new data source.After choosing object type and clicking Next button I get error

Wizard Form

An unexpected error has occurred. 
Error Message: The method or operation is not implemented.

Is there any way to fix it?

---

Indeed my major problem is my English language and think I gave false informations.
So I try again.
I have a C# Windows App project and  use Entity Framework entities as Data Sources in it.Every thing was OK at first and I had no problem in creating and using a data source from a particular entity in the models. but recently when I add Database tables  to my Entity Data Models ,I can't see them in my data source and if I try too add it by wizard I will get that error.When I click OK, the wizard closes immediately.Btw,I have some other projects in my solution and added a reference to them from my current project but  None of them have such a problem .
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you connecting SQL datasource or Oracle datasource..?

Comment: We are going to need a bit more information in order to help you out here.  Can you give us some more specifics on the data source that you are trying to add?  Have you tried repairing the installation to see if that fixed the issue?

Comment: Your Data Source should be "Microsoft SQL Server (SqlClient)" otherwise it might be the problem with your SQL Server Installation.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same Problem in our project. The reason was a corrupt c# file in the project. I've ceated a new project and copied all files in several steps into the new project. Each time I've checked the 'Add new data source' wizard until I've found the file.